# ¿Cómo sacar todos los parámetros de un input en php?

Tags: php, formularios

me gustaría saber como sacar todos los parametros de un input pongo un ejemplo:

imaginaros que tenemos el siguiente codigo:

```
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="textoinput" /><br />
    <br />
      <input type="checkbox" name="prueba" value="opcional" />Opcional<br />
     <br />
      <select name="pruebas">
       <option value="1">Opcion1</option>
       <option value="2">Opcion2</option>
      </select><br />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

y yo quiero que con php me muestre los siguiente:

El input con nombre textoinput es de tipo texto y se a enviado (aqui iria el texto que se envie)

El input con nombre prueba es de tipo checkbox y el valor que tiene es opcional

El select con nombre pruebas tienen dos opciones con valor 1 y 2 y contienen Opcion1 y Opcion2

todo lo anterior seria mediante php y lo que devolvería, gracias de antemano.

Comment: si solo buscas mostrar lo que se envia por post puedes intentar `var_dump($_POST);`, esto te mostrará todo lo que retorna con sus tipos respectivos.

Comment: hola **Tehlgend** podrías ampliar un poco mas el desarrollo de tu pregunta, para poder ayudarte mejor, como ser en que momento quieres obtener esos datos?, desde donde quieres obtenerlos? y asi

Comment: Si, te explico yo tengo ese formulario y cuando le de a un botón de enviar este lo que hará aparecer justo debajo todos los datos obtenidos de los input y los select de que tipo es el input que valores tiene en caso de que los tenga, los nombres de estos input y del select igual.

Comment: Cuando mandas un formulario se crea un arreglo asociativo con dos datos: `('name'=>'value')` donde `name` equivale a lo que haya escrito en la etiqueta `name` del elemento y `value` es el valor que éste tenga. No se manda el tipo, no se manda nada si el elemento está vacío. Para hacer lo que quieres tendrás que 1) recoger vía Javascript los datos que quieres en un objeto así más o menos: `[{name: 'prueba', type: 'text', value:'opcional'},{name: 'pruebas', type: 'select', value:'1'}]`  2) mandarlo al servidor vía Ajax, 3) leer el objeto en PHP para determinar el contenido de cada cosa.